# Xcode Scroll View over full width and height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, constraints, scrollview

How can I create a Scroll View over the full width and height in different resolutions (for ex. iPhone 4, iPhone 6)?

What I try:
Select the Scroll View and use Autoresizing to scale it up:
[image]

This seems to work at first:
[image]

But xcode complains then about constrains errors:

[image]

And if I fix them the Scroll View loses its height and width:
[image]

What do I do wrong?

Comment: are you using AutoResizing or AutoLayout ?

Comment: I use Auto Layout

Comment: 1 , 2, 3 ,4 is text field ?

Comment: @balkaransingh Yes, those are textfields. How does this matter?

Comment: No this no matter . here issue is you not add proper constraint. here why you are using scroll view?

Comment: i mean if you wha show 1 2 3 4 text field you can show it without scroll view.

Comment: @balkaransingh this is just a dummy view for testing, the real view which I work on is more complex and a scroll view is needed. But I break it down to more simple parts in order to solve my bugs.

Comment: constraint are depend on other ui element  you can not break it down. plz post your complete ui you need .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `Size Class` to `Any Any` if it is not.
2. Select `ScrollView` and Click `Pin` button located at bottom.
3. Fill Top, Left, Bottom and Right Boxes with zero and click all four dashed lines, then click `Add 4 Constraints` button at bottom in popup.
4. Now to Resolve the Auto Layout issue, Select Scrollview and Click `Resolve the Auto Layout issue` button (last) located at bottom and select `Update Frames` option.

[image: Steps]

**Note**: If you want to use `ScrollView` with autolayout, you need to do  some more work. for e.g. Don't put subviews directly into ScrollView. Put `UIView` in `ScrollView` as container and put your all subview in it.
[Follow this tutorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did exactly what you wrote but after adding those 4 constrains it still dont scale: http://imgur.com/a/C800V

Comment: how you came to know that scroll view does not scale to full size ? Make sure you follow this steps for sizing class `Any Any`. To Edit Sizing class click on `w Any h Any` text located bottom bar` and then start from step 1.

Comment: as you can see in the screenshot in my last comment, the sroll view does not scale in the Preview window. Where can I select w Any h Any? At the botton I just can select different iPhone versions: http://imgur.com/GASAcPO

Comment: @iBlink check Updated GIF. At the start point of the video, it shows how to select size class.